# Could there be a special-function counterexample to Schanuel's conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory, special-functions, transcendental-number-theory, closed-form-expressions

It is not too hard to show that if [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) is true, then the only algebraic numbers admitting a "closed-form expression" (as defined precisely in [this paper](http://alum.mit.edu/www/tchow/closedform.pdf)) involving $e$, $\pi$, and other exponential-logarithmic constants are the ones solvable in radicals.

While reading Ken Ono's entertaining book *My Search for Ramanujan* recently, I was struck by the fact that some of Ramanujan's miraculous discoveries yield seemingly "transcendental expressions" for algebraic numbers.  This leads to my question: Could one exploit special-function theory to construct an explicit closed-form expression for an algebraic number that is not solvable in radicals?

I expect the answer to be no, since I expect Schanuel's conjecture to be true.  Still, even if that is the case, I wonder if there is any way to prove a precise theorem along these lines, that all closed-form expressions *constructed in a certain way* must be solvable in radicals if they are algebraic.  Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with special function theory to even tell if this question makes sense, but I was hoping some MO reader might be able to help.

**EDIT:** As an illustration, here's one of Ramanujan's results, reproduced from Douglas Hofstadter's book *Gödel, Escher, Bach*:

$${e^{-2\pi/\sqrt 5}\over\displaystyle \strut 1+{e^{-2\pi\sqrt 5}\over
   \displaystyle \strut 1+{e^{-4\pi\sqrt 5}\over
   \displaystyle \strut 1+{e^{-6\pi\sqrt 5}\over
   \displaystyle \strut {\ \atop 1+\cdots}}}}} =
{{\sqrt 5 \over \displaystyle \strut
   1+\root 5 \of
{5^{3/4}
   \biggl({\sqrt 5 - 1 \over 2} \biggr)^{\! 5/2}\!\! -1}}
   -{\sqrt 5 + 1 \over 2}}$$
This doesn't answer my question directly because the expression on the left is an infinite continued fraction, which isn't a closed-form expression in my sense, but it does make me wonder whether there could be an identity of this sort where the "$\dots$" on the left-hand side can be replaced by a terminating expression.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, some special cases of the hypergeometric function give roots of
polynomial equations whose Galois groups are not solvable.
The simplest examples are the solutions of $y(1-y)^t = x$ for rational $t$.
[Here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/catalan.pdf)
is one elementary proof of this formula (which can also be obtained by
Lagrange inversion);
[here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/catalan2.pdf)
is a simpler one that requires you to already have surmised the formula
some other way (e.g. experimentally).

Comment: It is known that every quintic equation can be reduced (perhaps with 
  extraction of a few roots) to a value of such a hypergeometric function.
  There are also modular functions that do the same trick via the
  icosahedral cover $X(5) \to X(1)$, though you have to evaluate both
  a modular function and the inverse function of one.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer that I had a very specific definition of "closed-form number" in mind, as you'll see if you follow my link.  I will edit.

Comment: Ah well -- I was misled by your invocation of Ramanujan, whose
 "transcendental expressions" freely used hypergeometric and modular functions.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit closed-form expressions for the implicit algebraic numbers are given in Umemura, H.: Resolution of algebraic equations by theta constants. In: Mumford, D. (Ed.): Tata Lectures on Theta II, Birkhäuser, Boston/Basel/Stuttgart 1984.

Look also here: [Understanding Umemura's Theorem for roots of algebraic equations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151498/understanding-umemuras-theorem-for-roots-of-algebraic-equations)

Jordan, C. has shown in 1870 that every algebraic equation can be solved by means of modular functions.

See King, R. B.: Beyond the Quartic Equation. Birkhäuser, Boston/Basel/Berlin 1996 for both approaches.