# Higher Cardano formulae in terms of $\Theta$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, polynomials, theta-functions

Consider a polynomial in one variable with complex coefficient

$$f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$$

we are interested in its roots. Babylonian solved for $n = 2$, and Cardano did it for $n = 3, 4$. Later group theorists (Galois and Abel et al) proved that radical solutions (i.e. expressions in $+-\times\div \sqrt[k]{\cdot}$) do not exist in general for $n \geq 5$. **However, exact solutions are available in general if we allow theta functions** [1][2].

In [1], the author very slightly modified $f(x)$ to $F(x) = x(x-1)f(x)$, and create a compact Riemann surface $$C_F := (y^2 = F(x))$$ which doubly branch-covered $\mathbb{C}P^1$, whose branch points are exactly the roots. Then, by specifying an order on the roots (assumed to be seperated), one can write down the period matrix $\Omega_F$ and the zeta function $\Theta(\vec{z}; \Omega_F)$. A root of $f$ can then be written explicitly in $\Theta$.

#### Questions

1. Instead of an explicit expressions of roots, I'd like to understand it from a higher point of view. We know that $\Omega_F$ is closely related to the function theory of the curve $C_F$. Why, in principle, is it capable of extracting the locations of the branch points over $\mathbb{C}P^1$?
2. The introduction of general $\sqrt[k]{\cdot}$ (in particular, imaginary numbers) was crucial for solving equations. What's remarkable in Cramer's formulae is that we essentially *only* have to blackbox the solutions to $x^k = c$. In this sense, what is the "typical" equation that $\Theta$ solves? (For $n=5$, see [Bing radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical).)

#### References

- [1] Umemura, H.: Resolution of algebraic equations by theta constants. In: Mumford, D. (Ed.): Tata Lectures on Theta II, Birkhäuser, Boston/Basel/Stuttgart 1984.
- [2] For an explicit formula, see MOF: [Understanding Umemura's Theorem for roots of algebraic equations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151498/understanding-umemuras-theorem-for-roots-of-algebraic-equations/)

Comment: 1. Theta functions are functions on the jacobian of the curve; one way to understand these formulas is to understand what happens to the branch points of $C$ via the Abel-Jacobi map $C\to Jac(C)$. 2) $\Theta$ is not really designed to solve any specific equation - note also that it depends on the curve $C$.

Comment: 2) Exactly. That's why I had this question. It seems like a nice coincidence. 1) Interestingly, a priori $p: C \to \mathbb{C}P^1$ doesn't say too much about $C$ itself. SO I wonder why the Abel-Jacobi map "sees" $p$.

Comment: Well, the map $p:C\to P^1$ determines $C$ uniquely up to isomorphism, because you can recover the branch points from where the map ramifies. In fact, this is why Umemura works with the curve $x(x-1)p(x)$ ranther than $y^2=p(x)$ -- he is forcing three of the branch points to lie at $0,1\infty$, so the remaining roots are determined by the cross-ratios (which appear in his formulas!).

Comment: Note also that the Abel-Jacobi map $C\to Jac(C)$ also allows us to recover $C$ (and thus the roots). In fact the image of $C$ under the composition of Abel-Jacobi with  $C\to Jac(C) \to Jac(C)/\pm$ is a rational curve inside the Kummer variety $Jac(C)/\pm$. The Theta constants allow us to write down a projective model for the map $Jac(C)\to Jac(C)/\pm \to P^N$ into some big projective space. Thus looking at the partial derivatives, one recovers the branch points.

Comment: @EnnioMoricone Conversely, is $C$ as an abstract Riemann surface (assume hyperbolic) enough to determine $p: C \to P^1$ (in particular, its set of roots)? I suspect this should be true, and due to this, we can write down $\Omega$ (up to permutation) from the Riemann surface $C$ itself. If both of these are true, these facts will be the answer to my question.

Comment: Yes - the following argument when the degree of $p$ is at least 5. The abstract curve $C$ is "hyperelliptic"; the canonical divisor $K_C$ determines a 2:1 cover $\phi:C\to P^1$ which is branched over some points $p_1,\ldots, p_{2g+2}$. Up to a change of coordinates on $P^1$, this $\phi$ coincides with the map $p:C\to P^1$ - so $\p$ is essentially determined by $C$. If we work with the curve $y^2=x(x-1)p(x)$, this rigidifies everything, so even the roots of $p$ are determined. When the degree of $p$ is $2,3,4$, the curve still admits such a map to $P^1$, but the map is not unique.

Comment: @EnnioMoricone Fantastic! So if I understand correctly: the if an abstract complex curve $C$ is hyperelliptic, then its canonical divisor $K_C$ determines a unique $2:1$ cover $\phi: C \to P^1$, branched over $p_1, \ldots, p_{2g+2}$. And if such curve $C$ comes from $y^2 = (x-x_1)\ldots(x-x_n)$ where $n \geq 5$ , then the roots form a subset of the branched points. This must be fundamental in the classical theory. Could you provide a reference or an argument to this? It deserves to be an answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, absolutely, this is all well and classical. Actually, in your notation, $n=2g+2$ and the $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are equal, up to linear change of coordinates, the $p_1,\ldots,p_{2g+2}$. A reference can be found in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry Chapter IV.5, but that might be a bit of an overkill. Perhaps better references are: Miranda's Riemann Surface book or in "Geometry of Algebraic Curves" by Arbarello-Cornalba-Griffiths-Harris.